# Mapping $\mathbb{Z}_k$ into $\{d,d+1,\ldots,d+k-1\}$ preserving value $\bmod k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I want to give a (simple) map $f:\mathbb{Z}_k \to \{d,d+1,\ldots,d+k-1\}$ for $d,k \in \mathbb{N}$ and such that $\forall i \in \mathbb{Z}_k. f(i) \bmod  k = i$.

Is there a particularly simple way of doing this?

**Goal**

The goal is to formally prove that if $f$ is periodic with period $k$ then $\sum_{m}^{m+k-1} f \; l = \sum_{m+d}^{m+d+k-1} f \; l$. The above is the particular case $m = 0$.

**Current solution (suggested by @kingW3)**

$f(i) = (i-d) \; mod \; k + d$  and if $g(j) = j \; mod \; k$ then $g \circ f = Id$.

I'm interested in showing $f \circ g = Id$. How can I do it?

Comment: Let $f(a+k\mathbb{Z}) = a \text{ mod } k$?

Comment: @Yanko there $f$ is not mapping onto $\{d,d+1,\ldots,d+k-1\}$

Comment: $f(i)=((i-d)\mod k)+d$

Comment: @kingW3 seems like working, the same  should work for $f:\{m,\ldots,m+k-1\} \to \{m+d,\ldots,m+d+k-1\}$  with $m \in \mathbb{N}$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one way to map $\Bbb{Z}_k$ onto a set of consecutive $k$ integer in such a way 
$$
f(\bar x)\equiv x\bmod k.
$$
That's because in any given set $K$ of $k$ consecutive integers there's only one $y\in D$ satisfying the displayed congruence for any given $\bar x$.
Thus, let $f(\bar x)=y$.